# Creating a table on Python using nested loops

Tags: python, python-3.x

While creating a table on python, I ran into an issue. Here is the code:

```
row = 5
col = 4
for x in range(1, row + 1):
    print("Row", x, end="")
    for y in range(1, col + 1):
        print(" Column", y, end="")
        print(" Row", x, end="")
    print()
```

This is what runs:

```
Row 1 Column 1 Row 1 Column 2 Row 1 Column 3 Row 1 Column 4 Row 1
Row 2 Column 1 Row 2 Column 2 Row 2 Column 3 Row 2 Column 4 Row 2
Row 3 Column 1 Row 3 Column 2 Row 3 Column 3 Row 3 Column 4 Row 3
Row 4 Column 1 Row 4 Column 2 Row 4 Column 3 Row 4 Column 4 Row 4
Row 5 Column 1 Row 5 Column 2 Row 5 Column 3 Row 5 Column 4 Row 5
```

As you can see it ends with rows and is missing column 5. What can I do to fix this?

This is the output that I expect:

```
Row 1 Column 1 Row 1 Column 2 Row 1 Column 3 Row 1 Column 4 Row 1 Column 5
Row 2 Column 1 Row 2 Column 2 Row 2 Column 3 Row 2 Column 4 Row 2 Column 5
Row 3 Column 1 Row 3 Column 2 Row 3 Column 3 Row 3 Column 4 Row 3 Column 5
Row 4 Column 1 Row 4 Column 2 Row 4 Column 3 Row 4 Column 4 Row 4 Column 5
Row 5 Column 1 Row 5 Column 2 Row 5 Column 3 Row 5 Column 4 Row 5 Column 5
```

Comment: What output did you expect?

Comment: @Sumit just edited the output I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code should do it:-

```
row = 5
col = 5
for x in range(1, row + 1):
    for y in range(1, col + 1):
        print(" Row", x, end="")
        print(" Column", y, end="")
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

Question is, you have initiated column as 4 and why do you expect it to print "Column 5". Is it something you want or is there something wrong with the logic you are trying to convey?